# Serve PHP site with suburl using NGINX

Tags: php, nginx

There is the following nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ { expires 2d; add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform"; }

        server_name myurl.com;
        client_max_body_size 32m;
        root /home/user/www/wordpress;
        index index.html index.php;

        location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
          gzip_static on;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
              include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
              include fastcgi_params;
              fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
              fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/user/www/wordpress$fastcgi_script_name;
              fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE post_max_size=20M;
              fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE upload_max_filesize=20M;
        }
}
```

It good works; if I visit myurl.com I can see my site. So, now I want that my site will be in myurl.com/suburl, not root url. How can I do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that this is a WordPress blog. The solution is to use an [`alias` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) to point to the WordPress installation and use [nested `location` blocks](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name myurl.com;
    client_max_body_size 32m;

    location ^~ /suburl {
        alias /home/user/www/wordpress;
        index index.php;

        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /suburl/index.php last; }

        location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ { 
            expires 2d; 
            add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform"; 
        }

        location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
            gzip_static on;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE post_max_size=20M;
            fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE upload_max_filesize=20M;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you will need to [change the HOME and SITEURL parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) within the WordPress blog to point to the new URL for the site.